# ASP.NET Core pipeline multithreading

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, asp.net-core

Does ASP.NET Core pipeline handle requests by multithreading?
If it does, how do you configure the number of threads?  And also, should singleton services be thread safe?

Comment: https://github.com/aspnet/benchmarks Look in the results section which answers your first question

Comment: Actually exactly this document forces me to ask this question! and I can see from this repository https://github.com/aspnet/benchmarks/blob/8c751ad8fd623caf568708d7d82e1b3498d90385/src/BenchmarksDriver/Program.cs the number of threads here is for client app, not for the server one!

Comment: _Like the Plain Text scenario above but with HTTP pipelining enabled at a depth of 16. Only stacks/servers that show an improvement with pipelining are included._. I doubt it'd be able to handle  1.2 million requests per second on a single server thread

Comment: Me to. Anyway what really matters here is how multithreading of server should be accounted by developer?

Comment: Try KestrelServerOptions.ThreadCount  https://github.com/aspnet/KestrelHttpServer/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel/KestrelServerOptions.cs#L90

Comment: I see! Thank you. What do you think about singleton service thread safety?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The first question was already answered in the comment above (look into [KestrelServerOptions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.server.kestrel.kestrelserveroptions))

Regarding thread safetly, the answer is in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection#service-lifetimes-and-registration-options):

> Singleton lifetime services are created the first time they are requested (or when ConfigureServices is run if you specify an instance there) and then every subsequent request will use the same instance. If your application requires singleton behavior, allowing the services container to manage the service's lifetime is recommended instead of implementing the singleton design pattern and managing your object's lifetime in the class yourself.

That means all requests for the service pull the same object, which means no per-thread objects, and thus no thread safety.

> **Thread safety**
>
> Singleton services need to be thread safe. If a singleton service has a dependency on a transient service, the transient service may also need to be thread safe depending how it’s used by the singleton.

Coudn't be more clear.  Since the objects are not created per thread, they are not thread safe by default (though it's possible some services are designed to be).

Comment: What about the impact in performance? What if we have a number of requests coming in depending on one instance to run some calculations. Isn't that a performance bottleneck?

Comment: I imagine that is an implementation detail.  Not everyone knows how to write proper multi-threaded code. ;)  That said, even if it was written properly, it's obvious you may have some requests waiting on a singleton for access, and those will delay until they get access.  If that is a problem, then don't use singletons! ;) (though perhaps it can't be avoided in some cases, like upating file data).