# Best practice for persisting tokens using Client Credentials flow

Tags: c#, identityserver4

I have an ASP.NET Core MVC application allowing anonymous users. This app is calling an ASP.NET Web API that is protected by Identity Server 4. I have created a client in Identity Server describing the MVC app (client) and given it access to the api scope like this:

```
new Client
{
    ClientId = "my-mvc-client-app",
    AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.ClientCredentials,

    RequireConsent = false,
    ClientSecrets = new List<Secret> { new Secret("this-is-my-secret".Sha256()) },
    AllowedScopes = new List<string>
    {
        StandardScopes.OpenId.Name,
        StandardScopes.Profile.Name,
        StandardScopes.OfflineAccess.Name,
        "my-protected-api"
    },
    RedirectUris = new List<string>
    {
        "http://localhost:5009/signin-oidc",
    }
}
```

In my MVC app, I'm using `TokenClient` to get a token that I can use when making requests to the protected API like this:

```
var disco = await DiscoveryClient.GetAsync("http://localhost:5010");
var tokenClient = new TokenClient(disco.TokenEndpoint, clientId, clientSecret);
var tokenResponse = await tokenClient.RequestClientCredentialsAsync("hrmts-test-candidate-api-scope");
```

This works fine, but I'm requesting new tokens from Identity Server on every request, which is probably not a good idea.

What is the best practice for handling the tokens? How can I persist them on the client (the MVC app) and how can I handle refresh tokens to make sure the client gets a new token when necessary?

Comment: Btw TokenClient is now obsolete (https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/issues/2885), you can use an extension method on the regular HttpClient. See for example https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/blob/master/samples/Quickstarts/1_ClientCredentials/src/Client/Program.cs

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to wrap that client in a managed service of some kind (as a singleton) so that you can use it anywhere you need. We have a token component that we use for server to server communication that follows this flow:

```
public class ServerTokenComponent
{
    private TokenResponse Token { get; set; }
    private DateTime ExpiryTime { get; set; }
    public async Task<TokenResponse> GetToken()
    {
        //use token if it exists and is still fresh
        if (Token != null && ExpiryTime > DateTime.UtcNow)
        {    
            return Token;
        }     

        //else get a new token
        var client = new TokenClient("myidpauthority.com","theclientId","thesecret")
        var scopes = "for bar baz";

        var tokenResponse = await client.RequestClientCredentialsAsync(scopes);

        if (tokenResponse.IsError || tokenResponse.IsHttpError)
        {
            throw new SecurityTokenException("Could not retrieve token.");
        }

        //set Token to the new token and set the expiry time to the new expiry time
        Token = tokenResponse;
        ExpiryTime = DateTime.UtcNow.AddSeconds(Token.ExpiresIn);

        //return fresh token
        return Token;
    }
}
```

Comment: I like the approach however, if this is scoped as a singleton is this implementation thread safe and re entrant safe?

Comment: If you use the method AddSingleton to register the service, it is guaranteed to be thread safe, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/43303280/9266796

Comment: @JohanMaes actually thread safe means special way to handle class properties|fields and (some times) methods when certain resource is accessed from the several threads. Singleton is in thread safe way by the container, but it can contains some thread unsafe code

Answer (score 4):

In other words - you need to cache that token somehow. When you request the token, you get an ExpiresIn in the response - this will tell you how long the token will be valid.

Another option is to wait until the API returns a 401 - and then request a new token.

Refresh tokens are not used with client credentials flow.